# Bad Request error when calling from jquery ajax to API contrroller ASP.net Core

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to call an api from a page with button click via ajax call. Problem is that for GET & DELETE , the call is working but for POST and PUT, it says bad request format in firefox debugger.

```
namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class JsonDataAPIController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET: api/JsonDataAPI
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET: api/JsonDataAPI/5
        [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "Get")]
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST: api/JsonDataAPI
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody] string value)
        {
             //check for value and do stuff
        }

        // PUT: api/JsonDataAPI/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE: api/ApiWithActions/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

function call in html page

```
function apicall() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'api/JsonDataAPI',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {value:'1234'},
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log("success");
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("error");
            }
        }).done(function () {
             //console.log("ajax");
        })
    }
```

Ultimately i want to send JSON data via ajax and do work in API.I do know that if I do not send any contenttype and datatypein ajax call then it will automatically assign.  Then why this string data is not working , i'm not able to get. Why is there ControllerBase in API? Shouldn't it be APIController ?

Also when I tried to use Postman, the API's do not even get called. If i try to access api via url in firefox then it can access the GET api but when the same URL is used in POSTman it says "Could not get any response". I've not enabled any authentication while setting up the project and also in postman, i set the parameters properly (like no authentication), still from the postman the call wont work.
Sorry but I'm learning hence so many questions.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Problem is that for GET & DELETE , the call is working but for POST and PUT, it says bad request format in firefox debugger.

Please try to modify your code like below.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'api/JsonDataAPI',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify('1234'),
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log("success");
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log("error");
    }
}).done(function () {
        //console.log("ajax");
})
```

Comment: it works but i do not understand as to how a string datatype can accept data which is sent as json. can you explain a bit, please ? thank you for the answer .

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with API. Since you're passing the string value as HTTP POST, you need to use the javascript code like this.

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: "/api/JsonDataAPI",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: "=1234", // add an = sign
    success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log("success");
    },
    error: function () {        
        console.log('error');
    }
});
```